# Could not find encryption dll dbfips16.dll with Sql Anywhere 16

Tags: c++, encryption, dll, sqlanywhere

I have the problem, that if i deploy my 64bit application on a customer computer, i get the error message:

> encryption dll "dbfips16.dll" could not be loaded.

The curious thing is, that on my notebook and some other computers it's working pretty well. I tried to add the dll's to our deployment, but could not find it in the Sybase 16 directory, do i have to download the seperatly?

(I currently i did not want to use any encryption)

P.S. i use simple file based deployment.

**EDIT**

I use the sybase 16 ADO.net driver (c#).

The problem only appears on one server.

**EDIT**

```
server=***;dbn=***;charset=utf-8;links=TCPIP;UID=***;PWD=***;ENC=None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dbfips16.dll is only loaded when the connection string tells the client to use FIPS-validated encryption. If you don't want to use encryption at all, the ENCRYPTION parameter should not be set, or should be set to "none". Also check to make sure that the SQLCONNECT environment variable is not set (or doesn't contain the ENCRYPTION parameter).

If this doesn't help, can you post the contents of the connection string and/or DSN?

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Thank you for your help, but setting `Encryption=None` in the connection string does not help. Could you tell my, why i can not find the fips-dll in the sybase directory? Even not in the developer edition.

Comment: The FIPS library is a extra piece that you have to pay for. Can you post the connection string? Or can you add the "Log=temp.txt" connection parameter, try again, and then post the contents of the temp.txt file?

Comment: Ok, the problem was not the fips-dll, if i add `log=sybase.log` to the connection string, the log says that i have a version conflict with: `dbrsa16.dll`. If i add this dll to my deployment (directory) it works. Should i add the complete bin64/bin32 dll of the developer version to the deployment? (Besides the license file, which will be generated with our bought license i think). P.S.: on page 18, this file does not mention `dbrsa16.dll`: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/303c7dca-e1c5-3010-1c9a-fe56def3288c?overridelayout=true

Comment: You shouldn't need the whole bin64/bin32 directory but dbrsa is definitely required. I will try to get the deployment document corrected. Thanks for pointing this out.