# Could not load the encryption DLL "dbfips16.dll" in SQL Anywhere 16

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to connect my C# application to a SQL Anywhere 16 database and I keep getting the same error in staging server.

> Could not load the encryption DLL "dbfips16.dll" in SQL Anywhere 16

I'm using dotnet core and [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5/) nuget package. I've already tried put `ENC=NONE` in connection string and checked `SQLCONNECT` environment variable, that I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33286457/4084610) question. (which doesn't exits)

*PS: I don't want to use encryption.*

Here is my code. The error is thrown at `con.Open();`

```
public virtual T ExecuteQuerySql<T>(
      Func<IDbConnection, T> exec
      , IDbTransaction transaction = null
  )
  {
      var hasTransaction = transaction != null;
      var con = transaction?.Connection ?? GetSAConnection();
      if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
          con.Open();
      var ts = transaction ?? con.BeginTransaction();
      try
      {
          return exec(con);
      }
      finally
      {
          ts.Commit();
          if (!hasTransaction)
          {
              ts.Dispose();
              con.Dispose();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is your source code?

Comment: @AnEpicPerson added an example :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer! 
I changed the nuget package from `iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5 16.0.0.20433` to `16.0.0.19484` and it works just fine now :)